# Introducing an array to store scores in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The question I am working on is:

Write a program that:

asks the user how many exam scores there are (and verifies that the user entered a positive integer), prompt the user for each real-valued score, one by one (as shown below in Sample program behavior / output: box), Calculate and output the average of the scores and count and output how many scores are greater than the average (as shown below in Sample program behavior / output: box).

Sample program behavior / output:

How many exams scores do you have to enter? 5

Enter score #1: 95.0

Enter score #2: 92.0

Enter score #3: 68.0

Enter score #4: 72.0

Enter score #5: 70.0

The average score is: 79.4
There are 2 scores larger than the average.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int examnum = -1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        while (examnum<0) {
            System.out.println("How many exam scores do you have to enter?");

            examnum = scan.nextInt( );
        }


        for (int i=1; i<=examnum; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter score #" + i + ": ");

            for (int a=1; a<=i; a++) {
                a = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

What I did produces the following output however my problem is that I need to store the scores that are input to later compute an average so inside my for loop I would need to store the scores as an array but I do not know how to approach that.

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial about arrays in Java. You need to learn how to declare an array, story elements in an array, and access elements in the array. The official Oracle tutorial will show you how to do all of this and more.

Comment: please refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: `What I did produces the following output...`. What output?

Comment: You could store it in array after creating Array -- int score[] = new int[NUMBER_OF_EXAMS] and store it while taking user input.  int i = 0; score[i++] = a(basically user input). Or you could use ArrayList. Better read tutorial about Array in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prompt looks good however there is one small problem.

**Hint:** What condition would you use for your **while** loop if you wanted to ensure that the value entered was not **less** than **1** since zero would be rather non-productive?

*It's always nice to inform the User of any invalid entry.*

---

To place items into an Array you need to declare that array and initialize it to the proper size:

```
int[] scoresArray = new int[examnum];
```

Think about this, where do you think this line of code should be placed?

**Hint:** You need to ensure that the required array size is **already** properly established.

---

Why use two **for** loops when you can use only one? What can the second (inner nested) **for** loop do that the outer **for** loop just simply can't do?

**Hint:** Nothing! `"Enter score #" + (i+1) + ": "`. Of course *in this case* `i` (within the [initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) section) would need to start from **0** and always be less than **examnum** (within the [termination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) section).

---

If you want to *add an element to* your array, where do you think would be a great place in your code to do that?

**Hint:** `int score = scan.nextInt(); scoresArray[i] = score;`.

---

> **Things to consider:**

When **scores** are being entered, do you think the User entries should be validated? What if the User enters one or more (or all) alpha characters instead of digits in any of your prompts that require an Integer value? Do you end up getting an **InputMismatchException**? How would you handle such a thing?

Yes, you can nest **while** loops within a **for** loop and visa-versa.